# How do I modify this regex to not match '&' in Python?

Tags: python, regex

**Background**

I would like to extract a piece of information out of a string. For example,

NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) 8-9:30AM TUES & FRI

Because it's only `TUES` and `FRI`. It's not a range of days so I would like to just get `['TUES', 'FRI']`

However, for something like

```
2 HOUR PARKING 9AM-5PM MON THRU SAT
```

It would be a range of days so the result would be 
`['MON', 'TUES', 'WED', 'THURS', 'FRI', 'SAT']`

I have this regex which works with a range of days but I would like to modify to except just one rule.

```
\b((?:(?:MON|MONDAY|TUES|TUESDAY|WED|WEDNESDAY|THURS|THURSDAY|FRI|FRIDAY|SAT|SATURDAY|SUN|SUNDAY)\s*)+)(?=\s|$)
```

It works with

```
NO STANDING 11AM-7AM MON SAT
```

which extracts `MON` and `SAT`. But I don't want it to match

```
NO PARKING (SANITATION BROOM SYMBOL) 8-9:30AM TUES & FRI
```

Because I have another regex which I want it to be matched.

Comment: What are the actual requirements? I doubt adding `(?!\S+\s*&)(?<!&\s)` to the beginning is a good solution. Also, consider changing your regex to something more linear, like `\b(?:(?:MON|TUES|THURS|FRI|SUN)(?:DAY)?|WED(?:NESDAY)?|SAT(?:URDAY)?)\b(?:\s*\b(?:(?:MON|TUES|THURS|FRI|SUN)(?:DAY)?|WED(?:NESDAY)?|SAT(?:URDAY)?\b))*`.

Comment: I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many regex I would suggest running them in specific order (give them a priority) such that the more specific regex / more important ones will match first. That way you could stop matching if one regex matched, in your case the "other" regex.